# Analyzing a "ranking" question on a survey

Tags: survey, ranking

I gave a survey to Volunteers. Now I am not sure how to code a certain question, so I can evaluate.
The question is "Please rank what motivates you to....? (1 = most motivating, 2 - 2nd most...).  There are 7 items which they then rank.
e.g. ___spiritual convictions,   ___peer support,   ___social benefits

For each volunteer's response, Do I code each item separately (1, 2 ... or 7)?

Then, what type of statistics will best show, highest motivators?